# Jquery and form validation in dialog popup

Tags: jquery

I have a form in a jquery dialog. Validate everything via jquery but have problems with the rules for required, min and max. Only the first of the 3 is working.

Was searching for 30 minutes now but my knowledge of jquery syntax is let's say basic.

Below the Code: min validation is working. max and required not. What part I miss here?

```js
function validate() {
  var valid = false;
  
  $(':input[min]').addClass('ui-state-error')
  $(':input[min]').each(function(i, elem) {
    if (elem.value == '') {
      valid = false
      return valid
    } else {
      valid = true
    }
    // valid = true
  })
  return valid

  var valid = false;
  $(':input[max]').addClass('ui-state-error')
  $(':input[max]').each(function(i, elem) {
    if (elem.value == '') {
      valid = false
      return valid
    } else {
      valid = true
    }
    // valid = true
  })
  return valid

  var valid = false;
  $(':input[required]').addClass('ui-state-error')
  $(':input[required]').each(function(i, elem) {
    if (elem.value == '') {
      valid = false
      return valid
    } else {
      valid = true
    }
    // valid = true
  })
  return valid
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as execution hits your first `return` statement the function will exit, hence only the first iteration completes.

To fix this, join the selectors in to one jQuery object and iterate through them in a single loop:

```js
function validate() {
  var valid = false;
  var $inputs = $(':input[min], :input[max], :input[required]');
  
  $inputs.addClass('ui-state-error').each(function(i, elem) {
    if (elem.value == '') {
      valid = false
      return valid
    } else {
      valid = true
    }
    // valid = true
  })
  return valid;
}
```

It's also worth noting that the code can be made more succinct using `filter()`:

```js
let $inputs = $(':input[min], :input[max], :input[required]');      

let validate = () => $inputs.addClass('ui-state-error').filter((i, elem) => !elem.value.trim()).length != 0;
```